# Form Datefield passing None to post data form in django

Tags: python, django

I used boostrap datepicker for the datefield that capture date of birth, the problem i have is the datefield returning None which result to an error  (1048, "Column 'st_dob' cannot be null").

**model.py**

```
    st_dob = models.DateField()
```

**forms.py**

```
    st_dob = forms.DateField(label='Date Of Birth', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'dob_datepicker'}))
```

**view.py**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

    if student_form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST.get('st_dob'))
```

My part of boostrap date picker look like this

```
 $('.dob_datepicker').datepicker({
         endDate: new Date(),
         autoclose: true, // close after insert
         format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
     });
```

So it works on getting other post data but for this datefield it return none

**#Edits**

I edited using this : print(student_form.cleaned_data['st_dob']) although i get the data posted but the problem is my save function it always give null dob

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
st_reg_no = forms.CharField(label='Student Reg No', max_length=200, required=True)
st_other_name = forms.CharField(label='Other Name', max_length=200, required=False)
st_dob = forms.DateField(label='Date Of Birth', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'dob_datepicker'}))
# st_dob = forms.CharField(label='Date Of Birth', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dob_datepicker'}))
gender_choice = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female')
)

st_gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='Gender', choices=gender_choice)

st_phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number', max_length=200, required=False)
st_nationality = forms.CharField(label='Nationality', max_length=70)
st_city = forms.CharField(label='City', max_length=70)
programme = ProgrammeChoiceField(queryset=Programme.objects.all())
campus = CampusChoiceField(queryset=Campus.objects.all())
st_image = forms.ImageField(label='Upload Picture', required=False)

# for Hiding helptext for userCreationForm
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StudentSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for fieldname in ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']:
        self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')
@transaction.atomic
def save(self):
    # user = super().save(commit=False)
    user = super(StudentSignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.is_student = True
    user.save()
    # get instance of user above and adding it to student table
    student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
    student.st_reg_no = self.cleaned_data.get('st_reg_no')
    student.st_other_name = self.cleaned_data.get('st_other_name')
    student.st_dob = self.cleaned_data.get('st_dob')
    student.st_gender = self.cleaned_data.get('st_gender')
    student.st_phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get('st_phone_number')
    student.st_nationality = self.cleaned_data.get('st_nationality')
    student.st_city = self.cleaned_data.get('st_city')
    student.programme = self.cleaned_data.get('programme')
    student.campus = self.cleaned_data.get('campus')
    # student.st_image = self.cleaned_data.get('st_image')
    student.save()
    return user
```

Comment: Don't think it is your problem, but you should be getting the value in the view from `form.cleaned_data['st_dob']`, not from request.POST.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?if yes, how did you do it